# Is there an OSS or algorithm to calculate total 3D space necessary for many 3D objects?

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

Sort of like a 3D tetris calculator. For instance:

Given this list of sizes (in cm here), calculate the minimum necessary three-dimensional space required.

```
40 x 35 x 55
60 x 35 x 25
55 x 45 x 30
110 x 55 x 45
45 x 30 x 33
```

(Specifically this is for calculating storage space required for a bunch of different sized boxes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a variant of the [3D box packing problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201133/how-to-pack-3d-boxes-into-a-bigger-box), which is NP-complete, so no, there is no algorithm, but some heuristic methods can approximate solutions.